# How to use scientific tick label axis format with \times as separator and scaled ticks = false?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Why is the line

```
 tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,sci,sci generic={mantissa sep=\times,exponent={10^{#1}}}}
```

not workint correctly? The exponent is missing. I want to use the tick label number format 1 x 10^n for my y-axis, with \times as seperator.

MWE:

```
% used PGFPlots v1.14
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
scaled y ticks=false,
y tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,sci,sci generic={mantissa sep=\times,exponent={10^{#1}}}},   
ymin=0,
ymax=1000,
]

 \addplot [domain=0:1000] {x}; 

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: try `y tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,sci},` ... :)

Comment: @Zarko: that gives me a \cdot as separator -  I want \times. But the exponent n is there with your line of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
yticklabel={%
  \pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,
    sci,sci generic={mantissa sep=\times,exponent={10^{##1}}}
  }%
  \axisdefaultticklabel
}
```

or

```
yticklabel={$\pgfmathprintnumber
    [sci,sci generic={mantissa sep=\times,exponent={10^{##1}}}]
    {\tick}$%
}
```

to get

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      scaled y ticks=false,
      yticklabel={$\pgfmathprintnumber
          [sci,sci generic={mantissa sep=\times,exponent={10^{##1}}}]
          {\tick}$%
      },
      ymin=0,
      ymax=1000,
    ]
    \addplot [domain=0:1000] {x}; 
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: nice answer! is this somewhere documented (in manual)?

Comment: @Zarko It should be in the PGF manual

Comment: @percusse, I expect this, but so far with my search in PGF as well in TikZ manual  I found only result for `\pgfmathprintnumber`, but the step from there to proposed solution in above answer was to huge :-( ,   so I ask where to look. Now it is slightly smaller :-) clear ...

Comment: @Zarko Check page 953 in PGF manual (v3.0.1a)

Comment: @Zarko Additionally see the description of `yticklabel` in the `pgfplots` manual. Then the only step is using `##1` instead `#1`.

Comment: @esdd, if the `pgfplots` manual would have an example about this, than this be easy ... anyway,I,m preaty sure that I read all about tick labels styling, but seems that I overlooked this. But now I store your answer in my collection of interesting answers and alo learn from it. thank you!